# How can I get data from one table based on another table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a working database

[image: 1]

How do I get users sorted by descending rating from it (the user's rating is the average rating of the content created by him).

I wrote the following query, but it does not work correctly, namely, the average rating value of the content created by the user is displayed incorrectly
[image: 2]

Comment: (1) Put the query you are using as *text* in the question, not an image.  (2) Explain what you want to see.  (3) Why is a missing rating considered `0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from users u
left join (
   select userid, coalesce(avg(evaluation),0) avgrating
   from ratings
   group by userid
) rt
 on u.userid = rt.userid
order by avgrating desc
```

Comment: Thank you, I realized where I was wrong. Please tell me how to output 0 in the average score column instead of null. I got the following answer: 
UserId                                                                    Rating
4e40b9c0-58f1-4659-adb3-66b285a09b2b          null

b2cea130-f5dd-4e98-9cec-626da5a08d12           3

Comment: @pled you can use `coalesce(avg(evaluation),0)`

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the average rating to use:

```
avg(ratings.evaluation)
```

I see no reason to impose a rating of `0` where there is no rating.